# Why negative \vspace skips less space than specified in LaTeX

Tags: spacing, geometry, vspace

I have code like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=0pt, right=0pt, top=50pt, bottom=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{show frame}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{-50pt}
Hello!
\end{document}
```

I skip the amount of space that equals the top margin. So I expect the text to appear at the top of the page with no margin at all. However it seems like the `\vspace` skips less space than expected. In fact if I write `\vspace*{-5pt}` it moves the text in the opposite direction. Why does it happen and how to specify skipped/added space precisely? I do need this 50pt margin at the top of the page but sometimes I need some content to protrude into the margin on some pages. And I need to be able to specify spacing accurately.

Comment: Not tested.  The first line has its baseline at `\topskip`, so I suspect you may also have to `]vspace{-\topskip}`.

Answer (score 1):

add `\showoutput`

with no space you get

```
...\glue(\topskip) 3.05556
...\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x597.50787, glue set 557.23004fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 H
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 l
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 l
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 o
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 !
```

so `\topskip` is set to make the baseline of the first line 10pt from the top, so 3pt is added with the rest coming from the height of H.

With `\vspace*{-5pt}` you get

```
...\glue(\topskip) 10.0
...\rule(0.0+0.0)x*
...\penalty 10000
...\glue -5.0
...\glue 0.0
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0
...\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x597.50787, glue set 557.23004fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 H
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 l
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 l
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 o
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 !
```

as the first item is not text you get the full 10pt of `\topskip` then the -5pt so a total of 5pt. So, as you say, the negative space causes a larger space above the text.

---

So in short, `\vspace*{xxx}` will move the content the distance xxx from the position it would be in with `\vspace*{0pt}`.  The position it is with no `\vspace*` is (for reasonable sized first lines) the same as you get with `\vspace{-height of first line of text}`